# Twitter Bootstrap container class not balanced on the center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been starting to explore Twitter Bootstrap, and I tried to write or replicate some of their example codes. I used a div with their .container class for the wrapper, and added some rows and columns in it. Having a div with a .container class supposedly centers the div automatically, but in my case, I'm having an unbalanced content. The white space on the left side is much wider than the white space on the right side. Here's the code (I'm not using any css styles):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>The Room</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' />
    <!--responsive bootsrap here-->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"></div>
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <a href="#" class="brand">The Room</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Preview</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-search">
                        <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search for...">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- first row -->
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <h1>Hey Mark! <small>and everybody!</small></h1>
                <p>Hey Mark! I am Johnny, I am super boring, I love to play football, and I am very passionate about film making. I love the idea on sucking on making films, spending $6m for my first feature film, which is my masterpiece of course! The title of my masterpiece, is "The Room" very catchy right? No, I did not hit her! I did not hit her! I did NOT!</p>

                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Watch Movie</a>`enter code here`
                </p>
            </div>
        </div><!-- second row -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the screenshot:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/70465637/error_center.jpg

Notice how the left white space is wider than the right white space.

Help Please, thanks in advance.

Comment: Creating a row and then putting the content of the row (span12) outside the div has caused this issue.

Always place span or col element within the row element

Answer (score 2):

Your `div.span12` should be a child of `div.row`.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

replace body tag with  this

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="span12">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a href="#" class="brand">The Room</a>
                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Preview</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-search">
                    <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search for...">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- first row -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <h1>
                    Hey Mark! <small>and everybody!</small></h1>
                <p>
                    Hey Mark! I am Johnny, I am super boring, I love to play football, and I am very
                    passionate about film making. I love the idea on sucking on making films, spending
                    $6m for my first feature film, which is my masterpiece of course! The title of my
                    masterpiece, is "The Room" very catchy right? No, I did not hit her! I did not hit
                    her! I did NOT!</p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Watch Movie</a>`enter code here`
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- second row -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div></body>
```

Answer (score 1):

check your code properly your  `span12` div should come inside of `<div class="row"></div>`

your code should be something like this

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
      <div class="span12"> your content goes here </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having trouble with the whitespace after putting your span12 div inside your row, then it might be because Bootstrap specifies its own margins and padding etc.

You may have to set your own margins or padding for your span. You can override the bootstrap styles in your CSS with the !important declaration:

```
.span12 {
  margin-left: -50px !important;
}
```